Frequency of English words despite native equivalents in other languages: studies?
I am not a student of linguistics. However, I am learning Hindi, which is a fascinating language.
Are there studies on the frequency of English words - in a language where the country was colonised by Britain or America - in cases where a native equivalent exists but is less well-known?
Perhaps these studies relate that frequency to geographic, class or cultural factors?
The ultimate purpose is for me to know which to choose when talking to ordinary Hindi-speaking people. I am also a bit curious about other languages.

Which to choose? What do you mean?

I wonder, which part of the world were colonised by America (probably United States).


The ultimate purpose is for me to know which to choose when talking to ordinary Hindi-speaking people.

Studies don't help you learn languages.
And a study about language mixing in one scenario will not help you do language mixing in another scenario, because language mixing is just too specific to the way that the two languages co-exist in a milieu.
What we can say is that, as so often with language, language mixing is both flexible and governed by rules.  For example, in scenarios where Spanglish arises, you cannot just randomly choose which word to say in English and which to say in Spanish.
Essentially it becomes another aspect of the language to learn, and the best way to learn is practice.

I know they don't help me to learn it directly, but I am curious to look at the statistical evidence. I go to Malaysia, Philippines, etc. often on vacation, and over there language mixing is common too. The thing about Hindi is, the choice of mixing depends hugely on geography, demography, age etc. And in a city like Delhi where they all mix, it's a nightmare for me. Reading studies would help me get a bird's-eye view of the factors that even native speakers are possibly not fully aware of.
